# Castle windsor security exception

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor

I developed a small WCF service that uses Castle Windsor IoC container and it works 
fine on my PC. When I deploy it onto a Win 2008 R2 server and host the 
WCF service in IIS 7 it fails with the following error. I checked the 
server level web.config and the trust level is set to "Full". What do 
I need to do to get this to work. As a test I deployed the same service as it is onto a Windows 2003 server with the trust level set to "Full" and it works fine. I am 
unable to figure out what setting/configuration I am missing on the 
2008 server that is making the service fail.

Stack Trace:

[SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted 
callers.] 
   Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer..ctor() +0

WMS.ServiceContractImplementation.IoC.IoCInstanceProvider..ctor(Type 
serviceType) in D:\WCF\WCFProofOfConcept\WMSServices 
\WMS.ServiceContractImplementation\IoC\IoCInstanceProvider.cs:19

WMS.ServiceContractImplementation.IoC.IoCServiceBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehav­ior(ServiceDescription 
serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) in D:\WCF 
\WCFProofOfConcept\WMSServices\WMS.ServiceContractImplementation\IoC 
\IoCServiceBehavior.cs:24

System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(Ser­viceDescription 
description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +377 
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +37 
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen() +27 
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +49 
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan 
timeout) +261 
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String 
normalizedVirtualPath) +121 
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String 
normalizedVirtualPath) +479

Comment: Also posted in the Castle group: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/2ed4ed2b32d57822

Comment: Since you solved this problem would you mind posting the solution and making it as answered?

Solution is here: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/0da71be71b16904d.

Detailed discussion on the issue can be found here: http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/2ed4ed2b32d57822

Answer (score 0):

Agree with FryHard, the tip on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/castle-project-users/Dacb5xsWkE0 resolved the issue for me.

However to make it easier,

- Download Streams.exe from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx
- Use the command "Streams -d -s [Directory path]" to unblock all files at once.